# Hyperlink screen tip causing workbook to need repairs

Tags: vba, excel

I am using VBA to create hyperlinks to cells in different sheets in Excel and when I add a screen tip everything works fine until I close the workbook.

Upon reopening, Excel makes repairs and forces me to open read only. Getting rid of the screen tip solves the problem but having the screen tip is incredibly convenient.

Does anyone know what might cause this?

```
Hyperlinks.Add wb.Sheets("Summary").Cells(j, i + 2), "", "'" & i & "'!" & wb.Sheets(i + 1).Cells(3, col).Address, scrTip
```

Edit:

Here is the code I am using to create scrTip.

```
scrTip = ""

For indx = 0 To 4

      If TopCost(indx) <= 0 Then Exit For

      If indx > 0 Then scrTip = scrTip & vbCrLf
      scrTip = scrTip & strTopCost(indx) & " - " & Round(TopCost(indx))

Next indx
```

Array strTopCost contains descriptions that can have symbols like ",-,&,/, #, etc while the topcost array contains a number. The screen tip shows the location of the hyperlink when scrTip is empty.

Comment: It probably would have been helpful to provide one or more sample screen tips (you know... the things causing your trouble...) so that an experienced eye could look for illegal characters, etc.

Comment: The screen tips themselves contain stuff that my company may not want on the internet but I did add the code that declares scrTip as well as examples of what types of symbols might be included. All of the data comes from cells.

Answer (score 1):

Please give the following a try:

```
wb.Sheets("Summary").Hyperlinks.Add _
    AnchorAnchor:=Cells(j, i + 2), _
    Address:="", _
    SubAddress:="'" & i & "'!" & wb.Sheets(i + 1).Cells(3, col).Address, _
    ScreenTip:=scrTip
```

Also, make sure to delete any existing hyperlinks prior to creating new ones:

```
Dim hyp As Hyperlink
For Each hyp In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary").Hyperlinks
    hyp.Delete
Next hyp
```

Comment: Good call on deleting the hyperlinks, I had forgotten that. The same thing still happens with that formatting though.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. Some of the screen tips were too long so I limited their length to 25 characters and it worked fine afterwards.